# np.where() equivalent to df.loc()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am just practicing\learning pandas, and I am using the Pokemon dataset
from Kaggle.

The following two lines of code work fine, and produce the exact same result:

```
df.loc[df['Type 1'] == 'Fire', 'Type 1'] = 'Flamer'

df['Type 1'] = np.where(df['Type 1'] == 'Fire', 'Flamer', df['Type 1'])
```

Both replace the value 'Fire' in the column 'Type 1' with 'Flamer'.

However, I am trying to replicate that same behavior over multiple columns.
In the following two lines of code, the first one works, the second fails.
Exact error is also supplied:

```
df.loc[df['Total'] > 500, ['Generation', 'Legendary']] = 'TEST VALUE'

df[['Generation', 'Legendary']] = np.where(df['Total'] > 500, 'TEST VALUE', df[['Generation', 'Legendary']])
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mark/PycharmProjects/main/main.py", line 152, in <module>
    df[['Generation', 'Legendary']] = np.where(df['Total'] > 500, 'TEST VALUE', df[['Generation', 'Legendary']])
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (800,) () (800,2)
```

I do not understand what that error is trying to tell me.

Can I not replicate:  df.loc[df['Total'] > 500, ['Generation', 'Legendary']] = 'TEST VALUE'  using np.where()?

Comment: Try : `np.where( df['Total'].values[:,None] > 500,..`. Or maybe even - `np.where( df[['Total']] > 500 ..`.

Comment: Or maybe jut try using .where from pandas

Comment: @Divakar, that was it.  Re-post so I can accept as the answer.

Comment: @MarkS Would encourage you to post your own findings as a self-answer. Feel free to use code(s) from the posted comment.

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out by @Divakar , my syntax was wrong.  df['Total'] > 500 needed to be: df[['Total']] > 500 in my np.where() line of code.

```
df.loc[df['Total'] > 500, ['Generation', 'Legendary']] = 'TEST VALUE'
```

is successfully replicated by:

```
df[['Generation', 'Legendary']] = np.where(df[['Total']] > 500, 'TEST VALUE', df[['Generation', 'Legendary']])
```

I then took it a step further and gave the 'Generation' and 'Legendary' columns their own unique values.

The following two lines of code also generate the same, correct results:

```
df.loc[df['Total'] > 500, ['Generation', 'Legendary']] = ['Test 1', 'Test 2']

df[['Generation', 'Legendary']] = np.where(df[['Total']] > 500, [['TEST 1', 'TEST 2']], df[['Generation', 'Legendary']])
```